# Weird behavior in SharePoint library set up to require content approval

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2019

We have a form library in SharePoint and configured it to require content approval.

[image: Library Settings --> Versioning Settings]

I observed that whenever an item in this library is approved via the Approval/Rejection image button in the ribbon (please see picture below) the Modified column of this item gets updated but the Last Modified column value remains unchanged.

[image: Approve/Reject button in SharePoint ribbon]

After i change the approval status of the item using the Approve/Reject button i observed that the Modified column value gets updated but the Last Modified column value remains unchanged.

I saw this happening in a form library (library having InfoPath forms) but my colleague informed me that she observed this occurrence in a document library as well.

Just wanted to check if anyone else has seen this behavior. In a situation like this i am wondering how am i supposed to get the name of the person who did the approval or rejection of the item?

BTW this was on SharePoint 2019.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you create a SharePoint workflow on the library above and set it to fire when item gets updated, then the workflow Initiator will be give the name of the person who did the content approval of the item.

You will not be able to get this by looking at the Last Modified.